# Is there a way to annotate every line of a code block?

Tags: java, annotations, fxml

I have something like this in my code, only I have more FXML elements, so there is a lot of @FXML

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Player, String> playerColumn1;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Player, String> playerColumn2;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Player, String> playerColumn3;
```

I would like to anotate every line of code of some block with same annotation, something like this, is there a way to do it?

```
@FXML
{
    private TableColumn<Player, String> playerColumn1;
    private TableColumn<Player, String> playerColumn2;
    private TableColumn<Player, String> playerColumn3;
}
```

Comment: Second case will become as instance initialization block!!!

Comment: I bet some smart regexp could do it with a search and replace.  I could do it with 'private' but I dunno about using newline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the source code of ElementType (enum of allowed values for the @Target meta-annotation)

```
public enum ElementType {
    /** Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration */
    TYPE,

    /** Field declaration (includes enum constants) */
    FIELD,

    /** Method declaration */
    METHOD,

    /** Parameter declaration */
    PARAMETER,

    /** Constructor declaration */
    CONSTRUCTOR,

    /** Local variable declaration */
    LOCAL_VARIABLE,

    /** Annotation type declaration */
    ANNOTATION_TYPE,

    /** Package declaration */
    PACKAGE
}
```

What you are trying to do is not possible